Extract Files : Unsupported Method : arm64\libSkiaSharp.dll
It seems that the "Extract Files" task stopped working after version 1.244.1. I tried manually editing the task.json and task.loc.json files to change the minor version to 245, but it still doesn't work. I couldn't find a solution anywhere online. Is there a way to fix this issue, or do I need to wait for a new version?
Thank you for providing detailed information if possible.


Extraction failed for file: E:\Tools\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.220.5\_work\r1\a\_Package\test\test.7z 
code: 2 
stdout: 
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21
Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 26793475 bytes (26 MiB)
Extracting archive: E:\Tools\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.220.5\_work\r1\a\_Package\test\test.7z
--
Path = E:\Tools\vsts-agent-win-x64-3.220.5\_work\r1\a\_Package\test\test.7z
Type = 7z
Physical Size = 26793475
Headers Size = 3836
Method = 0A LZMA2:24 BCJ
Solid = +
Blocks = 3
Sub items Errors: 2
Archives with Errors: 1
Sub items Errors: 2
 
stderr: ERROR: Unsupported Method : arm64\libHarfBuzzSharp.dll
ERROR: Unsupported Method : arm64\libSkiaSharp.dll
 
error: undefined;




I use the Extract Files job agent.

Please share the pipeline definition, and pipeline debug log to show more details. Please check the link if it helps.

You can share the task screenshot if it's classic UI task, and pipeline log details screenshot. in addition, are you using self-hosted agent or Microsoft-hosted agent?

i edit my post with the error

On self-hosted agent, the 7z version comes from the task downloaded as below:

Please try to install latest 7zip version(24.08) on the agent machine, and specify the zip.exe in the task.

It will use the new version for the task:

If the issue persists, please compress the source file with the latest 7zip.

It works ! You are a genious, thanks !

Glad to know it helps! Happy coding!
